# Add a type to a class

Tags: c#

I have a simple classe called Device

```
public class Device
{

public string ID { get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Serial {get; set;}

public Device()
{
}

}
```

With what variable could I define this Device type ?

This device can be or printer, or phone, or computer.. I have tried with a string :

```
public string DeviceType {get; set;} //e.g : this.DeviceType = "Phone";
```

But I find it not elegant. How else could I add a Type for this device ? With enum?

```
enum DeviceType
{
PHONE,
PRINTER,
COMPUTER,
TABLET
}
```

Any ideas of a nice way of doing this ?

Comment: Um, an enum seems reasonable, but I'd use idiomatic names (`Phone`, `Printer` etc) instead of shouty ones. It's not clear what else you're lookingn for... Alternatively, you could make it an abstract class and have different subclasses, if you want to add behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm just looking for another way of implementing a Type for this device Class and avoid using a string

Comment: So use an enum, as you'd already decided. It's not clear what you're asking - you have a potential solution, and you haven't presented any reason not to use it...

Comment: DeviceType should be of type int. its an enumeration after all, and each item inside it has an assigned integer value. e.g. DeviceType.Phone should return "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it right...  But depending on what you're doing, consider other devices as well.

```
enum DeviceType
{
   PHONE,
   PRINTER,
   COMPUTER,
   TABLET,
   APPLE_TV,
   AMAZON_FIRESTICK,
   ROKU, 
   XBOX, 
   PLAYSTATION, 
   MISC_DEVICE    /*Just in case the device being used isn't on the list*/
}
```

If you explain a little more of what you're trying to do, we could help you a little more.